# CSS: put h1 on image

Tags: css

I have the following situation. I have an image ( tag) and heading ( tag). I want to place heading on the image. How can I do it?

I tried to use negative margin http://jsfiddle.net/58H7c/1/ but in this case image lay on the heading. I tried to play with z-index - no effect.

Maybe you know better solution?

TIA!

PS

One another idea is to use image as a background. But in this case when I try to do padding for #imgPlace container - background image is stay on place (when the div-container was moved).

Answer (score 6):

The correct way to do it:

1. Put them both in a container with `position:relative;`.
2. Put `position:absolute;` on the H1 only.
3. Put `z-index:1` on the H1 only.
4. Alter `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom` offsets of the H1 according to needs.
5. Profit.
6. Profit some more because you didn't break the flow of other surrounding elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/Trv2n/

Answer (score 2):

For image

```
   z-index:1;
   position: relative;
```

For heading

```
    z-index:10;
    position: relative;
```

Comment: Right, z-index needs element to be positioned by `position: ...`.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/58H7c/4/

I used absolute positioning to put the header 5px from the left and top.

Comment: Why the negative margin on the image?

Comment: @AlinPurcaru, That was already there. Thanks for the notice, I removed it.